# How to Save the wordcloud in R

Tags: r, word-cloud, wordcloud2

Can you please help to save word cloud on my local drive as an image?, I am looking for a code/command to get it done automatically through R Programming. I have tried with `saveWidget`, `plotly`, `orca` but not get success.

I have used below code to create the word cloud.

```
library(wordcloud2)
wordcloud2(demoFreqC, figPath = figPath,color = "orangered",fontFamily = "Miso")
```

Comment: Dupe here with code for displaying in .Rmd: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850987/4549682

Answer (score 8):

The procedure [is outlined here](https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/8). Briefly:

```
library(htmlwidgets) 
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
library(wordcloud2)
hw <- wordcloud2(demoFreq,size = 3)
saveWidget(hw,"1.html",selfcontained = F)
webshot::webshot("1.html","1.png",vwidth = 1992, vheight = 1744, delay =10)
```

Comment: I have tried this code but not able to get the output can you please tell me where the output got stored, as it is not showing in my current working directory.

Comment: Should be in your working directory if everything worked. I had to add `library(htmlwidgets)` to get `saveWidget()` working.

Comment: the HTML file 1.html saved in my working directory and I am able to access it but not able to find the 1.png file.

Comment: If `webshot()` ran without error, it has to be there somewhere :)

Comment: Your working directory is probably set to something you don't expect @sanjaysaini .  Check your Rstudio options to see where your working directory is, or use `getwd()`.  Always best to specify absolute paths to files when working in Rstudio.

Comment: Delay seems to work with 5s for me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850987/4549682).  It needs to be large enough to let the wordcloud render.  Might be machine-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RStudio, there is an option to import the output as image on the IDE itself.

Comment: I am not looking to download it manually.

Answer (score 0):

in R studio there is an option to export the plot in JPG or PNG format with the image size you want.

Comment: I am not looking to download it manually.