# R: Spreading the words in wordcloud

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm struggling to spread the words when using `wordcloud` function.

```
data = tibble(Day = c("January", "February", "March" , "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Semptember", "October", "November", "December"),
              Freq = c(1294, 1073, 1071, 1019, 938, 912, 703, 680, 543, 201, 190, 343))

set.seed(10)
wordcloud(words = data$Day, freq = data$Freq, min.freq = 1, 
          random.order=T, scale=c(3,.5), rot.per = 0)
```

I tried to save the output using `ggsave` function but this is what I got:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: not sure if we have any such parameter to do so, but as a work around, you can zoom it and then save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this in `wordcloud` but `wordcloud2` gives rather more flexibility. I managed to cobble together this with help from another SO question for saving as an image file.

```r
#packages enable saving to png or pdf via html, see link at end of answer
library(webshot)
webshot::install_phantomjs()
library("htmlwidgets")


library(tibble)
library(wordcloud2)

data = tibble(Day = c("January", "February", "March" , "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Semptember", "October", "November", "December"),
              Freq = c(1294, 1073, 1071, 1019, 938, 912, 703, 680, 543, 201, 190, 343))


set.seed(10)

# control appearance with wordcloud2 arguments. The padding between words is controlled by `gridsize`.
# You have to play around with `size`, `gridSize` and the image size

eg <- wordcloud2(data, size = 0.4, rotateRatio = 0, color = "black", gridSize = 75)


# save as html
saveWidget(wc,"wc.html", selfcontained = F)


# and then as image:png
webshot("wc.html","wc.png", delay = 5, vwidth = 480, vheight = 480)
```

For saving the image to file see: [How to Save the wordcloud in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759893/how-to-save-the-wordcloud-in-r)

And you end up with:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>